# Segmentation fault on ubuntu, Run on debian

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, coredump

Amazing enough at least for me. The code below cause `segmentation fault: core dump` on my ubuntu 15.04 but run successfully on my friend debian platform.

Also to note, I know that my `array` has desired indexes, so I get storage for that and indexes have integer value.

```
int array_dequeue(int **array, int *n)
{
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < *n - 2 ; c++)
        *array[c] = *array[c + 1];
    *n--;

    return 0;
}

//Calling that in main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int length = atoi(argv[1]); // ./mpi.o 4 so length is 4
    int *VP;
    VP = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<vertices; i++)
    {
        VP[i] = i + 1;
    }
    array_dequeue(&VP, &length);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the definition and initializing part. This could be the source of the segfault.

Comment: Did you run the program in a debugger? Did you `ulimit -c` to allow creation of a coredump? Did you `catchsegv` the program to get a stacktrace? Did you run it under `valgrind`? Did you recompile with `address-sanitizer`? No? Why not?

Comment: @SirPython I edit my question, thanks for note

Comment: What's in `vertices` ?

Comment: Change `*n--` to `(*n)--`; postfix `--` binds more tightly than `*`, so you're decrementing the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: or just use `--*n`, since you're throwing away the preval anyway. And you may want to look at the [operator precedence chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). It may change your understanding of what `*array[c]` really means.

Comment: @1nflktd sorry I edit the code

Comment: @JohnBode I did that thanks but problem exists

Comment: Did you check whether `argc > 1`?  `atoi()` wouldn't like a `NULL`-pointer.

Comment: Again. look at [the operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of C, then consider what `*array[c]` actually does.

Comment: @EOF I'm sure about it, also when I `printf("%d", *n)` in `array_dequeue` function I could see the number

Comment: Please don't keep putting the corrections in the question, it makes comments look irrelevant, hard to follow. Put them in the code you have.

Comment: Please rollback to revision two.

Comment: "Segmentation fault on ubuntu, Run on debian", you did not specify what means for you "The code below cause segmentation fault: core dump on my ubuntu 15.04 but run successfully on my friend debian platform.". Did you compile it on both (debian and ubuntu) or you compile it on one and try to run it on other ? i'm 100% sure that there is no way to compile that code on Ubuntu or Debian in that format or maybe you are not showing us the whole code. Anyway there are a lot of missing things there. What exactly is "vertices" and how did you managed to run that for ?

Comment: Where did you exactly declared that i ? The whole thing here is a bad joke. What do you expect from *n-- ?

Comment: @Michi you're intensively strict. Of course I don't have any problem in declaration and because of showing portion of code, that you said happened. Also are u sure about compiling on ubuntu and running on debian??? How you get that from my question. Any way thanks to `WhozCraig`, I get my answer, do not bother yourself buddy.

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi Make yourself an Idea ==>> http://ideone.com/yeUqhQ

Comment: @Michi thanks for down vote and either your simulation, but our attitudes are different, beside commentators told me not to change and edit the code because the comments will look irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the order of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) when you perform this statement:

```
*array[c] = *array[c + 1];
```

You *think* this means "dereference `array`, then take the `c` and `c+1` elements from the resulting array, etc..

What this *actually* means is: "Take the `c` and `c+1` *pointers* from the pointer-to-pointer base `array`, then dereference those.

In other words, it should be this:

```
(*array)[c] = (*array)[c + 1];
```

Frankly, I see no reason to pass that pointer by address in the first place.

And as mentioned in comments, you have further issues with operator precedence with:

```
*n--;
```

which decrements the pointer `n`, then evals the prior value of `n` by dereference, then ignores the result of that eval and marches on. The value stored at `*n` remains unchanged. It should be either:

```
(*n)--;
```

or simply:

```
--*n;
```

I prefer the latter, as you're throwing out the preval anyway. Regardless, spend more time studying the linked operator precedence chart.

Comment: thanks a lot, but do you have any idea why it did work on debian?!

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi I see no earthly reason why it should have worked *at all* on any platform. You were invoking undefined behavior with the `array` deref-subscripting i pointed out, so once that happened *anything* could result, including the blind-squirrel-finds-a-nut scenario and something actually appearing to *work*.

Comment: anyway I appreciate your patient and nice description

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi no problem. keep a link to that site i linked. It is an *outstanding* reference for both C and C++ (one of the best imho).